# Changing color of text in div on hover? - CSS

Tags: html, css, text, colors

Basically I have a button which is white but has a purple border and the text is purple and when the user hovers over the image, I want the background-color to be purple and the text to be white. Right now, I can get the background-color to switch from white to purple but I cannot get the text to switch from purple to white. THis is the code that I have at the moment: 
HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?page=learnmore"><div class="learnMore"><h3>LEARN MORE</h3></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
.learnMore {

width:140px;
height:35px;
border:1px solid purple;
margin:0 auto;
}

.learnMore:hover {
background-color:purple;
color:white
}
```

I have no idea why the color:white will not change the color. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Works fine for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lkk4ec3/). Maybe it's the missing `;`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think i have a missing ; , I think this may have something to do with my other styles or something. Right now what I can do is 
.learnMore h3:hover {
color:white
}
but the only problem with this is that the color of the text only changes when I am actually hovering over the text not just the box. Sorry about the question, I thought I had a syntax error or something where I used the wrong selector.

Comment: Seems you have other CSS rules that are conflicting with these. If `.learnMore h3:hover { color:white }` is working for you, you could try `.learnMore:hover h3{ color:white }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a semi-colon after color:white, you also may want to consider browser defaults for link visited colors etc.  Here is a working demo: [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/amandakremser/pen/EVaeRg)

```
.learnMore {
  background-color: white;
  width:140px;
  height:35px;
  border:1px solid purple;
  margin:0 auto;
  color: purple;
}

.learnMore:hover {
  background-color:purple;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for this, I have tried this with the semi colon but I still have  the same error, I think its got something to do with the rest of my website/other random selectors.

Comment: Are you using any sort of css reset or normalize?

Comment: Stupid me.. i had another selector that was overriding the :hover. I fixed it now and it looks great! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that an `h3` is a block element and `a` is an inline element. Prior to `HTML5`, the correct way to structure this would be with an `a` wrapped in an `h3`, e.g.:

```
<h3><a href="#">Learn More</a></h3>
```

With `HTML5`, it is now okay to wrap block elements with `a`. I would go with something along these lines:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    a.learnMore {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: purple;
    }
    a.learnMore h3 {
      border: 1px solid purple;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    a.learnMore h3:hover {
      background-color: purple;
      color: white;
    }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<a href="index.php?page=learnmore" class="learnMore"><h3>Learn More</h3></a>
```

```css
a.learnMore {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: purple;
}

a.learnMore h3 {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

a.learnMore h3:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.php?page=learnmore" class="learnMore"><h3>Learn More</h3></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case, you need to use a great css feature called a direct descendant combinator. ">"

it will be like this :

```
.learnMore {
    width:140px;
    height:35px;
    border:1px solid purple;
    margin:0 auto;

    &:hover {
        background-color:purple;
    }

    &:hover > h3 {
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

source : [treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/flexbox-buttons-text-color-not-changing-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are applying the style to the entire DIV not the text itself.

Add a `id` to the `<h3>`

```
<a href="index.php?page=learnmore"><div class="learnMore"><h3 id="t">LEARN MORE</h3></div></a>
```

Add this to your css

```
    #t:hover{
    text-decoration: none;    
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

Then just edit the colours you and the position

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8nexutg/)

Comment: Yeah but when I use this code, the text will only change from purple to white if I am actually hovering over the text but I want the color to change when I am hovering over the box.